# C check all neighbors of a element in a 2d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've been thinking if there is any smarter solution if I want to check all eight neighbors of an arbitrary element in a binary number only 2D array in C

What I do is:

Psudo Code:

```
//return how many neighbor of an element at x,y equals 1.
int neighbor(int** array, int x, int y)
    if x>WIDTH
        error
    if y>HIEGHT 
        error
    if x==0
        ignore west, nw, sw, and calculate the rest.....
    etc..
```

this is pretty dull, is there any smarter solution?

Answer (score 3):

I used a similar approach to get `Adjacent Mines` for a particular cell in the `Minesweeper Game`. What I did, is I used an Array like this (MAX_NUMBER_OF_CELLS = 8) :

```
int offset[MAX_NUMBER_OF_CELLS][2] = {
                                            {-1, -1},
                                            {-1, 0},
                                            {-1, 1},
                                            {0, -1},
                                            {0, 1},
                                            {1, -1},
                                            {1, 0},
                                            {1, 1}
                                         };
```

Considering we are talking about the `CELL` at `location 0, 0` in a matrix. We will simply add these offset values, to the `CELL` to check, if the adjacent CELL is a valid CELL (i.e. it falls within the matrix). If it is **VALID**, then we will see if it contains `1`, if yes than increment `sum` by `1` else not.

```
//rest of the values represent x and y that we are calculating
(-1, -1)           (-1, 0)               (-1, 1)
           -------------------------
 (0, -1)   |(0, 0(This is i and j))|     (0, 1)
           -------------------------
 (1, -1)           (1, 0)                (1, 1)
```

---

```
sum = 0;
for (k = 0; k < MAX_NUMBER_OF_CELLS; k++)
{
    indexX = i + offset[k][0];
    indexY = j + offset[k][1];
    if (isValidCell(indexX, indexY, model)) // Here check if new CELL is VALID
                                            // whether indexX >= 0 && indexX < rows
                                            // and indexY >= 0 && indexY < columns
    {
        flag = 1;
        if (arr[indexX][indexY] == 1))
            sum += 1;
    }
}
```

### EDIT 1 :

Here is one working example (C is not my language, though still tried my hands on it to give you one idea :-)) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int findAdjacent(int [4][4], int, int, int, int);

int main(void) 
{
    int arr[4][4] = {
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
    int i = 2, j = 2;
    int sum = findAdjacent(arr, i, j, 4, 4);
    printf("Adjacent cells from (%d, %d) with value 1 : %d\n", i, j, sum);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int findAdjacent(int arr[4][4], int i, int j, int rows, int columns)
{
    int sum = 0, k = 0;
    int x = -1, y = -1; // Location of the new CELL, which
                        // we will find after adding offsets
                        // to the present value of i and j
    int offset[8][2] = {
        {-1, -1},
        {-1, 0},
        {-1, 1},
        {0, -1},
        {0, 1},
        {1, -1},
        {1, 0},
        {1, 1}
    };
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        x = i + offset[k][0];
        y = j + offset[k][1];
        if (isValidCell(x, y, rows, columns))
        {
            if (arr[x][y] == 1)
                sum += 1;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

int isValidCell(int x, int y, int rows, int columns)
{
    if ((x >= 0 && x < rows) && (y >= 0 && y < columns))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible optimization, if you want to know the number of neighbors of cells a lot more than you want to change the cells, is to preprocess the number of neighbors for each cell and save the results in an another array.

```
int** actualArray;
// fill in with 0s and 1s
int** numberOfNeighbors;
// write a function to calculate the number of neighbors for cell x,y in actualArray and
// store the result in numberOfNeighbors[x][y]
preprocess(actualArray, numberOfNeighbors); // call this whenever actualArray changes
// now you can get the number of neighbors of a cell in constant time
// from numberOfNeighbors[x][y]
```

Comment: I mean the out of bound check

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find the current position of the element in the array? If so, you can define a macro like:

```
#define OFFSET(x,y) ((GridWidth*y)+x)
```

Or, if you're trying to find which surrounding 'boxes' could contain an element (i.e which neighbors are 'in bounds')...

```
for k = 0 while k < GridWidth
    for m = 0 while m < GridWidth
        if k < GridWidth
            toRight = true
        if m < GridWidth
            toDown = true
        if k > 1
            toLeft = true
        if m > 1
            toUp = true
```

From there, combine the directions to get diagonals - `if toRight && toUp, then toUpRight=true` etc

EDIT - I forgot to mention, this is if the grid is stored in a 1d array. For 2d, m would be for GridHeight